# VBA Conditional Formatting of specific Borders

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting, linestyle

Hej,
So I am trying to use VBA to add conditonal formatting to compensate for some other coding, which changes the ranges from time to time. My problem is, that I only the conditional formatting to apply to `xlEdgeRight` and `xlEdgeLeft`. However, VBA always tells me that it cannot set the border style. Any ideas?

```
Dim rngMark As Range
Dim DateCond As FormatCondition
Dim BordNum As Long

Call wsDef
Set rngMark = wksS.Range("E11:CPB25")

rngMark.FormatConditions.Delete
Set DateCond = rngMark.FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(TODAY()>=E$7,TODAY()<F$7)")
DateCond.SetFirstPriority
With DateCond
    .StopIfTrue = False
    .Font.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
End With
For BordNum = 7 To 8
    With DateCond.Borders(BordNum)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Color = -16776961
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
Next BordNum
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Programming formatconditions - especially borders - is a bit special.

You have to use `xlLeft` = -4131 and `xlRight` = -4152 in this case:

```vb
Dim BordNum As Long
Dim arrBordNum(1) As Long
arrBordNum(0) = -4131   'xlleft
arrBordNum(1) = -4152   'xlright
For BordNum = 0 To UBound(arrBordNum)
    With DateCond.Borders(arrBordNum(BordNum))
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Color = -16776961
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
Next BordNum
```